# Combine Price and QTY in Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1.7, custom-template

I want to combine block with price and block with quantity. QTY block without button "add to cart".

I found in theme's catalog file :

`Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml`.

I see qty block template. And I found file

`/magento_root/app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/amount/default.phtml` with price block.

How can I combine these two template?

I try to copy block what I want, but I have exeption.

Answer (score 1):

I understood that it's not easy and decided to find more easily way.
I put two blocks in wrapper and move this block after product info.
Then I move blocks with CSS.
In my case:

```
<container name="product.info.price.wrapper" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-info-price-wrapper" />
<move element="product.info.price.wrapper" destination="product.info.main" after="product.info.stock.sku" />
<move element="product.info.price" destination="product.info.price.wrapper" before="-" />
<move element="product.info" destination="product.info.price.wrapper" after="-" />
```

Comment: I require to show price box besides the qty input but this solution might help for simple product layout only. For configurable products this will not work.